# making 2 animations wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I'd like to create a text animation that is composed of 2 different small animations. I don't know how to double it in the same animation.

```
<DoubleAnimation>
   <Int32KeyFrame...>
</DoubleAnimation>
```

For example, I would like to move my text letters along the wave  y=sinx  and after one period, I would like them to jump up and down for 5 seconds before they repeat the sine path

Answer (score 1):

Create a Storyboard to contain the two animations

Set the start time of the second animation to the duration of the first.

You can use KeyFrame animations to simulate a sine function but instead you could [use an easing function](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2009/10/23/new-wpf-features-easing-functions.aspx)

Then start the storyboard.

If you want the letters to tightly track the sine you will have to create a different setup [as you can see here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30090/Text-On-A-Path-in-WPF). Note that is is not an animation but you could animate the path and the letters could follow.